# IAsyncEnumerable<T> in ASP.NET Core, deploying on iis is not supported streaming behaviour?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IAsyncEnumerable<int> Get()
    {
        return FetchItems();
    }

    static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> FetchItems()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

The referenced article address is as follows:
[IAsyncEnumerable with yield in C#](https://code-maze.com/csharp-async-enumerable-yield/)

The correct effect should be as follows：[streaming behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMe5m.gif)

But when I deploy the program in IIS,It doesn’t work.

The result will still be cached and output at one time.

Can anyone tell me if there is a solution?

**HttpContext.Features.Get().DisableBuffering()
This works,Thanks @Jeremy Lakeman**

Comment: So there's some buffering going on when deployed to IIS?

Comment: `HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>().DisableBuffering()` might work?

Comment: At the beginning I was using .NET SDKs 7.0.100 (app version was targeted at .net6.0) and it was not working. However, having installed SDK 6.0.404 it started to talk as expected.
Potential issue: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/32747

Answer (score 0):

There is an IIS feature that can buffer asynchronous streams: Dynamic Compression. If the Dynamic Compression feature is installed for IIS, it will buffer and attempt to compress text-based responses.